# Problems with the ACGIP Conference Project

Tags: html, css

So I have already attempted to do this project by myself but the program I'm using as a sandbox seems incredibly picky at how one is to do it. Despite using examples and other aids to help get this done, nothing has worked. I'm having three separate issues that I think I have done correctly but, apparently, had not done correctly. The issues are as followed:

1. Script & Form Elements
2. The Regex
3. The Submit Button

The program will not tell me what's being done wrong either. Might I get some aid?

```
 <section>
        <h1>Conference Registration Form</h1>
        <p>Required Item (*)</p>
        <form action="http://www.example/cg/register" method="post">

            <!-- title -->
            <div>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="titleBox" list="titleList">
                <datalist id="titleList">
            <option value="Mr."></option>
            <option value="Mrs."></option>
            <option value="Ms."></option>
            <option value="Prof."></option>
            <option value="Dr."></option>
            <option value="Assist. Prof."></option>
            <option value="Assoc. Prof."></option>
          </datalist>
            </div>

            <!-- firstName -->
            <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fnBox" required>

            <!-- LastName -->
            <label for="lastName">Last Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lnBox" required>

            <!-- address -->
            <label for="address">Address*</label>
            <textarea name="address" id="addBox"></textarea>

            <!-- Company or University -->
            <label for="group">Company or University</label>
            <input type="text" name="group" id="groupBox">

            <!-- E-mail -->
            <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="mailBox" required>

            <!-- Phone Number -->
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number*</label>
        <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" required pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn">

            <!-- ACGIP Membership -->
            <label for="acgipID">ACGIP Membership Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="acgipID" id="idBox" placeholder="acgip-nnnnnn" pattern="^acgip\-\d{6}$">

            <!-- Registration Category -->
            <label for="regList">Registration Category</label>
            <select id="regList" name="">
          <option value="member">ACGIP Member ($695)</option>
          <option value="nonmember">ACGIP Non-Member ($795)</option>
          <option value="student">ACGIP Student ($310)</option>
          <option value="poster">ACGIP Poster ($95)</option>
          <option value="guest">ACGIP Guest ($35)</option>
        </select>

            <!-- Button -->
            <p><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue"></p>

        </form>

    </section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the best chance of getting your question answered, please ask a *specific* programming question about 1 topic rather than just throwing the whole problem at us. Break it down into pieces, see if the question has already been answered and (if not), ask again. We don't know what your assignment was, we can only answer programming questions.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you. I posted the first of the three issues here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082569/problems-with-the-acgip-conference-project-script-and-element-forms

Comment: @FireradFieritis sending people off on a wild goose chase looking at links doesn't cut it. The object is to help people help you by making their life easier with focused complete questions and details. You don't want to waste people's time. Please edit your answer and improve it. If people vote it down you'll lose points, when if you make it a good question you could gain reputation and site benefits.

Comment: I was trying to make things cleaner but alright. It was just a single link to click on, no harm or foul from me. Someone else looked at the code anyways and said that it was actually correct. The program I was using was bugged. So I suppose this issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the regex is wrong here.
it should be:

```
 <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneBox"  placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" required />
```

NOT

```
 <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number*</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" required pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn">
```

It gives an error every time. Cheers