# Problems with the ACGIP Conference Project: Script and Element Forms

Tags: html, css

Ok. I was informed to post one issue at a time so, thus, I will do such. The first issue is the Script and Form Elements. This is what the problem states:

*Add a script element to the document head that loads the cg_script.js file.*

*Scroll down to the section element and insert a web form element that employs the action at http://www.example.com/cg/register via the post method.*

*Add the labels and input boxes shown previously in the figure in the Introduction step and described in the figure below. Place the input boxes directly after the labels and associate each label with its input box control. You do not need to enclose the label and input elements with div elements.*

The issue is that the program will not tell me what is wrong with what I had done so I need some aid to help figure out where to go from here.

The code below detail what I had done for this already. I really have no clue what the program wants from me at this point. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
<section>
    <h1>Conference Registration Form</h1>
    <p>Required Item (*)</p>
    <form action="http://www.example/cg/register" method="post">

        <!-- title -->
        <div>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="titleBox" list="titleList">
            <datalist id="titleList">
        <option value="Mr."></option>
        <option value="Mrs."></option>
        <option value="Ms."></option>
        <option value="Prof."></option>
        <option value="Dr."></option>
        <option value="Assist. Prof."></option>
        <option value="Assoc. Prof."></option>
      </datalist>
        </div>

        <!-- firstName -->
        <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="fnBox" required>

        <!-- LastName -->
        <label for="lastName">Last Name*</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lnBox" required>

        <!-- address -->
        <label for="address">Address*</label>
        <textarea name="address" id="addBox"></textarea>

        <!-- Company or University -->
        <label for="group">Company or University</label>
        <input type="text" name="group" id="groupBox">

        <!-- E-mail -->
        <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="mailBox" required>

        <!-- Phone Number -->
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number*</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" required pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn">

        <!-- ACGIP Membership -->
        <label for="acgipID">ACGIP Membership Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="acgipID" id="idBox" placeholder="acgip-nnnnnn" pattern="^acgip\-\d{6}$">

        <!-- Registration Category -->
        <label for="regList">Registration Category</label>
        <select id="regList" name="">
      <option value="member">ACGIP Member ($695)</option>
      <option value="nonmember">ACGIP Non-Member ($795)</option>
      <option value="student">ACGIP Student ($310)</option>
      <option value="poster">ACGIP Poster ($95)</option>
      <option value="guest">ACGIP Guest ($35)</option>
    </select>

        <!-- Button -->
        <p><input type="submit" name="continue" value="Continue"></p>

    </form>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

fix the phonenumber code line replace it with this

```
 <!-- Phone Number -->
<label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number*</label>
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneBox" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$"required/>
```